# React app rewired doesnt run under port 1024

Tags: reactjs, linux, ubuntu, continuous-integration, react-app-rewired

I have this React application that needs to run under port 443. Usually it works fine but now i got a new computer and for some odd reason i cant run it anymore.

I have two ways for this. A custom script in the package.json file and it should also work when ran with sudo. `sudo npm start` or `npm run https`.

The port is defined in the .env file by default.

This is what my package.json looks like
[image]

When i run `sudo npm start` the expected behaviour is for it to run, without sudo, it should warn me that Admin permissions are required. This is what is happening with sudo aswell.

`$ sudo npm start`
[image]

or with the other command

`$ npm run https`
[image]

Not quite sure what to do in this situation. Anyone have any idea how to make it work ?

Comment: found anything?

Comment: one bad solution was to install react-app-rewired with sudo globally. This only worked for the `npm run https` command. However, this was a BS of a solution because from time to time it still gave me errors that react was conflicting with in-project react instance. Sorry for the bad answer. i guess the main reason with this is, that something went wrong with the node installation (`sudo node --version` vs `node --version` gave different results). Honestly no clue how to fix it. @oshhh

Comment: @oshhh Its a bit later now, but i found that running this command, fixed the issue `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=443`

Answer (score 1):

Running this command fixed the issue for me.

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=443
```